# Nodejs: how to check if spawn is successfull?

Tags: node.js, express, child-process, spawn

I am spawing a command from my express script, but I need to distinguish between error and success. I was looking for a `child.on('success'...)` function, but it doesn't exist.

This piece of code (of course) doesn't work.

```
app.get(myID+'/test/', function(req, res){ 
        var child = spawn('lbg');
        child.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log('Failed to start child process.');  
                res.status(404).send("Cannot send test command");
                return;
        });
        res.json({statusMessage: "OK", statusCode: "200"});

 });
```

In other words, I need to fire the correct response only, not both!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
app.get(myID+'/test/', function(req, res){ 
        var child = spawn('lbg');
        child.on('close', code => {
          if (code === 0) {
             res.json({statusMessage: "OK", statusCode: "200"});
          } else {
             res.status(404).send("Cannot send test command");
          }
        }).on('error', err => res.status(404).send(err)) ;
});
```

Comment: didn't work. Error: spawn lbg ENOENT, and the script exited.

Comment: Seems spawn cant find script. Try with absolute path for start.

Comment: Yaroslav, yes but I would like to catch also a wrong path error (ENOENT) or a not existing script

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.get(myID+'/test/', function(req, res){ 
        var child = spawn('lbg');
        child.on('error', err => {
          if (err) {
             res.status(404).send("Cannot send test command");
          } else {
             res.status(200).send("Ok");
          }
        });
});
```